# type 'text' is not a subtype of type 'string'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new on Flutter and i got this error.

`type 'text' is not a subtype of type 'string'`

I have a class

```
class _Message {
  int whom;
  String text;

  _Message(this.whom, this.text);
}
```

and I want to convert the `text` to a list using this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> led = messages.map((_message) => Text('${_message.text}')).cast<String> 
    ().toList();
  }
```

How should i solve this?

Comment: You're converting the object into a Text widget and not a String

Comment: thanks for the answer, why down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` is a Widget so you can't cast it to `String`.

Text Widgets are used to tell flutter how to render a String.
You also need to return a single Widget in the build method.

You probably just want to do

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: messages.map((message) => Text(message.text)).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Optional:

To get that `List<String>` you do

```
final List<String> led = messages.map((message) => message.text).toList();
```

So your build method could look like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final List<String> led = messages.map((_message) => _message.text).toList();
    return Column(
      children: led.map((message) => Text(message)).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like to get the last string of the list. If the last string is 'on', an image of a bulb will be displayed.

Comment: `final String lastItem = messages.map((_message) => _message.text).toList().last;`

Comment: try this:    

```return Column(
        children: messages.mapIndexed((index, message) {
      if (index == messages.length && message.text == 'on') {
        return const Icon(Icons.lightbulb);
      }
      return Text(message.text);
    }).toList());```


On top of your file you have to 
`import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Answer (score 0):

Text is a widget and not the same as a String Object. Therefore, you cannot  assign a list of type `Text` to a List of type `String`.

If you mean to return a list of `Text` widgets, then change `List<String>` to `List<Text>`.

And secondly, the `build` methods requires you return a `Widget` Object and nothing more.